# What is purpose of decryption of data at both the load balancer and then the web server?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing

I heard that to alleviate the web server of the burden of performing the SSL Termination, it is moved to load balancers and then HTTP connection is made from the LB to the web server. However, in order to ensure security, an accepted practice is to re encrypt the data on the LB and then transmit it to the web server. If we are eventually sending the encrypted data to the web servers, what is the purpose of having a LB terminate SSL in the first place ?

Comment: What if the load balancer needs to see the request headers in order to decide which web server to route it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A load balancer will spread the load over multiple backend servers so that each backend server takes only a part of the load. This balancing of the load can be done in a variety of ways, also depending on the requirements of the web application:

- If the application is fully stateless (like only serving static content) each TCP connection can be send to an arbitrary server. In this case no SSL inspection would be needed since the decision does not depend on the content of the traffic.
- If the application is instead stateful the decision which backend to use might be done based on the session cookie, so that requests end up at the same server as the previous requests for the session. Since the session cookie is part of the encrypted content SSL inspection is needed. Note that in this case often a simpler approach can be used, like basing the decision on the clients source IP address and thus avoiding the costly SSL inspection.
- Sometimes load balancers also do more than just balance the load. They might incorporate security features, like a Web Application Firewall, they might sanitize the traffic or similar. These features work on the content so SSL inspection is needed.

Comment: Can you please provide details around the second point ? How routing is done when no SSL Termination is done on LB and the application is stateful.

Comment: @AnitAggarwal: to cite myself: *"... basing the decision on the clients source IP address ... "*. Thus, same client will end up at the same backend server.

Comment: How do we get the clients source IP address if we are not decrypting the data ?

Comment: @AnitAggarwal: The client source IP address is OSI layer 3 information. Only application data are encrypted, not transport meta data like IP address.